# R: Non-overlapping bars in same group ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot barplot that looks like this:
[image]

But the bonus bar is overlapping the account recharge bar. I want these bars to sum op so the first bars for example need to be equal to 152 on the y-axis. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Working with facets is not ideal in my situation. I have to plot it in one graph.

This is an example of (a part of) my data:

```
data <- data.frame(
            sale_year_month = c("2020-04", "2020-04", "2020-04", "2020-05", "2020-05", "2020-05"),
            spending_type = c("Account recharge", "Bonus", "Account use", "Account recharge", "Bonus", "Account use"),
            spending = c(140, 12, 53, 222, 16, 224.50),
            grp = c(0,0,1,0,0,1)
```

This is the code I used to plot my ggplot:

```
ggplot(spending_aalst_totaal, aes(x = sale_year_month, y = spending, group = grp, fill = spending_type)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width = 0.7) +
  geom_text(aes(label = spending), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.5, color = "black", size = 4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkseagreen", "firebrick2", "darkseagreen4")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 45))
```

Thank you!

Comment: What code did you use to make that plot?

Comment: @DanAdams, my code for the plot is now displayed in the question.

Comment: Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using facets but it needs a group first so that bars can be arranged properly:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
data %>%
  mutate(Var=ifelse(spending_type %in% c('Account use'),'A','B')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Var,y=spending,
             fill=factor(spending_type)))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  facet_wrap(.~sale_year_month,strip.position = 'bottom')+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0,'lines'))+
  labs(fill='Var')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer It works but I don't want to use a facet because I want all the bars in one plot. Do you know how?

Comment: @ElineHaldermans It is the more practical way to reach the output, otherwise you would have to manually add other values to the x-axis that can be complex.

Comment: The output has to be in one graph because when there will be more months, it will be less structured